# Unable to compile and create maven project for hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, maven-2, orm

I am trying to create a Eclipse project from Hibernate tutorials under path
\hibernate-distribution-3.5.3-Final\project\tutorials\eg
using command line **mvn eclipse:eclipse**. But i am getting this error

```
Reason: POM 'org.jboss.maven.plugins:maven-jdocbook-style-plugin' not found in repository: Unable to download the artifact from any repository
```

Can anyone faced this issue with the latest release of Hibernate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know what version of the plugin you need but [JBoss has moved recently to Nexus](http://relation.to/15192.lace) and, while the previous repositories (mentioned [here](http://www.hibernate.org/sourcecode.html)) will stay online indefinitely, ultimate versions of stuff is pushed to their Nexus repo now. So I suspect that you need the following declaration somewhere:

```
<repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>jboss-public-repository-group</id>
    <name>JBoss Public Repository Group</name>
    <url>http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
  </repository>
  ...
</repositories>
```