# Hibernate website shows version 3.5, maven only showing 3.1rc2

Tags: java, hibernate, maven-2

Which maven repository has the latest hibernate core 3.5?

I have repository.jboss.com/maven2 and it only shows version 3.1rc2.

**The latest is suppose to have hibernate annotations in the core .jar I believe, mine doesn't.**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to compile and create maven project for hibernate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3068804/unable-to-compile-and-create-maven-project-for-hibernate), [How to compile hibernate project with maven?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2999077/how-to-compile-hibernate-project-with-maven).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked there?
http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/org/hibernate/hibernate/3.5.1-Final/hibernate-3.5.1-Final.pom

Comment: I have repository.jboss.com/maven2 yet I don't see it, very confused as I updated it also.

Comment: What dependencies are use using exactly? Are you using `hibernate` instead of `org.hibernate` (for the groupId) perhaps?

Comment: This accepted answer is not even correct and misleading. Just look at the links this question duplicates.

Comment: Really? The first link in the other answer says "You can continue to use the same release repository URL (http://repository.jboss.com/maven2) as we have been told it will remain active "indefinitely".", and repository.jboss.com does indeed contain the artifacts the OP was after. What's incorrect and misleading about that?

Comment: Yes, really. As I wrote: *while the previous repository will stay online indefinitely, **ultimate versions** of stuff is pushed to their Nexus repo now*. And as of today, the OP should use Hibernate **3.5.3** which is **only** available in the Nexus repo. So, while http://repository.jboss.com/maven2 remains live for old projects using it, this is not the right place to look for new projects.

Comment: Maybe it's not in sync yet. It's not clear from their documentation whether they'll keep to be in sync as far as I can tell (that same link suggests the main change is for developers, not users). This being said, you're right, it's probably wiser to use the new Nexus repository. I simply think the main problem the OP had was change of groupId, since the previous repository already had artifacts for 3.5 with the new groupId. (The problem would have remained if only the repository had been changed.)

Answer (score 1):

They [changed their repositories](http://relation.to/15192.lace) around a few months ago

```
<repository>
      <id>jboss-public-repository-group</id>
      <name>JBoss Public Maven Repository Group</name>
      <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
</repository>
```

See the [getting started guide here](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/MavenGettingStarted-Users).